# putIfAbsent() not working with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ConcurrentHashMap<byte[], Integer> dps =
         new ConcurrentHashMap<byte[], Integer>();

    System.out.println(dps.putIfAbsent("hi".getBytes(), 1));
    System.out.println(dps.putIfAbsent("hi".getBytes(), 1));
}
```

prints

```
null
null
```

Why doesn't it print a `1` on the second line?  I have read the semantics for `putIfAbsent` and it should be guaranteed to work.  (Note: this was distilled down from a large concurrent program... as you can see, it's now single-threaded.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> putIfAbsent() not working with ConcurrentHashMap

`"hi".getBytes()` is not a constant array so you are generating two different objects there.  If you did something like the following you will see your `1`.

```
byte[] bytes = "hi".getBytes();
System.out.println(dps.putIfAbsent(bytes, 1));
System.out.println(dps.putIfAbsent(bytes, 1));
```

The `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` methods on `byte[]` array are from `Object` which only looks at the *reference* of the object, not its contents.

Whenever you store something in a `Map` you need to make sure it overrides `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` methods unless you want to just compare references.  This is a Java FAQ.  See these docs: [Java theory and practice: Hashing it out](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html).

As @Mauren mentions in the comments, to use the *contents* of `byte[]` you are going to have to write a little class which wraps the `byte[]` and provides proper `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` methods.  Or as  @CostiCiudatu mentions, you can use a `SortedMap` and use a `Comparator` for `byte[]` which looks at the contents of the array.

As an aside, if `String.getBytes()` returns a `new byte[]` encoded with the `StringCoding.StringEncoder` class based on your character set, etc..

Comment: Just noticed if I change `byte[]` to `String` (and remove `getBytes()` of course), then I get the expected behavior.  But my `String`s are different objects, so by your logic it shouldn't work.  Or do I not understand?

Comment: Ok, based on your new edits, I understand: `String` compares contents, but `byte[]` compares references.  Highly non-intuitive.  Appears that using `byte[]` as a Map key is generally a bad idea, therefore.

Comment: @Fixee `String` has overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, that's why it works correctly with `String`.

Comment: Whenever you store something in a `Map` you need to make sure it overrides equals/hashCode unless you want to just compare references @Fixee.  Java FAQ: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Comment: @Fixee you can correct this behavior by implementing your own class which contains a `byte[]` but implements `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Or you can use a `SortedMap` (`TreeMap`, for instance) with a `Comparator` for byte arrays. This approach is used in HBase and it's suitable whenever creating wrapper objects for each byte array would be too expensive.